# Does adding cold water to evaporative air coolers actually produce colder air?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity, evaporation

Or should it be the other way around, because hotter water evaporates easier than cold water?

I know this sounds stupid, so just hear me out.

I use an evaporative cooler and add normal room temperature water. Someone told me to add cold water from the refrigerator to get better results. I intuitively thought that indeed cold water will produce colder air.

But as we all know evaporative coolers cool air by using the air to evaporate water which takes away heat from the air. So, we need the water to evaporate to cool the air. But we know that hotter water evaporates easier than cold water.

So, **should it not be the case that refrigerated water will actually not evaporate as efficiently and hence not produce cooler air than in case of room temperature water ?**

For what it's worth, I tried both and could not feel any noticeable difference, but of course, it was nowhere close to a controlled experiment. So, I would appreciate an answer about what does physics predict what would happen?

Comment: FWIW I can tell you from experience, growing up in Texas hot summers in the 1960s, all we had for cooling our house were evaporative coolers. When it was really hot we would run a lot of cold well water into them and they would definitely blow cooler for a while.

Comment: @AdrianHoward Okay, so we have your uncontrolled experiment saying colder water works and mine saying it does not. Hence, we need to see what other answers say about the physics involved.

Comment: If you use water from the refrigerator in your house, say goodbye to the nominal cooling - the refrigerator cools its contents by heating the kitchen!

Comment: @user121330 that is irrelevant, because The fridge is not a variable. It stays on , whether or not i use refrigerated water in the cooler or room temperature water in the cooler. Hence, that is not an issue. You can just assume, the refrigerator is in another room or another house .

Comment: The radio uses more energy when the volume is high, the computer heats the house commensurate with processor use and your refrigerator has to put the heat from that room-temperature water somewhere. It's those coils on the back - touch them while it's running if you don't believe me. I get that you want to ignore this but part of physics is learning how to think about things. People leave fans on in closed rooms they don't occupy because they ignore part of a problem, but adding energy to a system always heats it up.

Comment: " _I get that you want to ignore this but part of physics is learning how to think about things_ " I am not ignoring it, i am saying that it is not a variable. Whatever heat the refrigerator puts out, it puts it out irrespective of whether i put refrigerated water in my cooler or room temp water in my coler. Part of physics is isolating the variables and knowing which factors are not varying. So for the 2 cases i mentioned, the only variable is the temp of water i put in the cooler

Comment: I need to get some of this magical water that cools itself!

Comment: @user121330 You dont get it. When comparing 2 cases, you compare the variables. You do not compare the factors that stay the same. The refrigerator stays the same, in both cases. The only variable is what i put in the cooler. You dont like the refrigerator benig there. Assume refrigerator is in a different house. It does not make a difference.

Comment: I get it now! A magical refrigerator that works the same when you put cold items in as when you put warm stuff in it! I want that even more than the magical water.

Comment: @user121330 I would actually respond to you, if you addressed questions respectfully instead and pointed out what the issues with what i am saying are. I accept i might be wrong in some things, and if you want to discuss it, then fine. If you want to just be snarky and make smart ass comments, then there is no point addressing anything you say. So , if you actually want to discuss what the issues are then do so. Else you can keep your sarcasm to yourself. You might want to read the stack exhange policy about behaviour and conduct.

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry for being snarky. I'll be blunt instead. The fridge heats your house. If you add warm beer to it, it heats it more. If you add room-temp water to the freezer, it heats it more. When you take things in and out of the fridge, it heats your house more. You can say it's not a variable, but it clearly is. If you disagree, you are wrong. See [speed chilling](https://www.consumerreports.org/refrigerators/cool-refrigerator-features-worth-a-look/).

Comment: @user121330  Yes, blunt and direct works better. So, adding room temp water to freezer isnt an issue.  I do not add room temp water to freezer just so i can use it in cooler. irrespective of what water i put in cooler, fridge always has reserves of cold bottled water. That is not a variable. The only variable you mentioned, is the taking cold water out of the fridge part. This is theoretically correct. But i open , take out cold water, close, in 1 second. i agree that miniscule 1 second will be a factor with a miniscule effect  . But, surely not as much as " goodbye to the nominal cooling " ?

Comment: In thermodynamics, there are 4 hard rules given to us by the laws of large numbers. You must play, you can't win, you can't tie and you can't cheat. You are still trying to win. The "reserve water" came from somewhere and it was warmer before. The refrigerator DEFINITELY heats your house more when you use its cold water. The refrigerator IS a variable.

Comment: @user121330 The reserve water was put in the refrigerator days ago. I do not put water in refrigerator , only when i need to cool it for use in cooler. That water has always been there, It was put there days ago, temperature of room would have been slightly heated because of that days ago. But that wont matter on this day. I am not trying to win against thermodynamics. The only effect of refrigerator on this day, would be the 1 second i take to open and close the refrigerator while taking out the cold water

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've intuited two possibly relevant counteracting mechanism (of which none, one, or both might be negligible): colder water takes more energy to heat up, and colder water evaporates slower.

As a first stab at the problem, let's assume that the water evaporates at its well-defined supply temperature and that the rate of water evaporation is essentially the same at both temperatures. This is a good approximation if the water evaporates quickly under forced convection of hot, dry air—a pretty good description of a swamp cooler fed from a (room-temperature or cold) water flow. Here, the difference in water chemical potential (essentially, the concentration) between the liquid water and dry air in conjunction with a very high relative surface area drives rapid evaporation, and the water temperature doesn't have time to equilibrate at room temperature.

The [*enthalpy of vaporization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization) (also called the *heat of vaporization*) reflects the amount of "heat" needed to achieve evaporation, corresponding to the cooling effect applied to the surroundings. The amount reflects evaporation/vaporization at the given temperature, from liquid water to gaseous water. It does not require boiling.

[image]

The parameter expressed here is the specific enthalpy (i.e., per unit mass). If the water in both temperature cases is fed at a constant rate and evaporates quickly, then the per-mass enthalpy can act as a surrogate for the per-time enthalpy, giving us an effective cooling power rate. Try comparing the rate at which you need to replenish water. If the rate isn't lower for the colder water, then the above assumption is valid and the specific enthalpy translates easily into a cooling power. If the rates are different, then the specific enthalpy should be adjusted according to the mass rate to again obtain a cooling power.

The relative slope around 0°C to 50°C is clearly slight. We can estimate the slope from the difference between the heat capacity of liquid water and steam, about $4.2\,\frac{\mathrm{kJ}}{\mathrm{kg\,K}}$ and $1.9\,\frac{\mathrm{kJ}}{\mathrm{kg\,K}}$, or about $2.3\,\frac{\mathrm{kJ}}{\mathrm{kg\,K}}$. So by switching from water at 40°C to 10°C, for example, you'd increase the cooling effect by about $70\,\frac{\mathrm{kJ}}{\mathrm{kg\,K}}$, an improvement of about 3%. Put another way, the energy it takes to heat or cool a kilogram of liquid water is generally much less than its latent heat (the heat required to vaporize it) of thousands of kilojoules. This would account for the difference you experienced as being essentially imperceptible.

Alternatively, it may be the case that you're providing a large tub of water that evaporates slowly. Note that water away from room temperature will tend to equilibrate toward room temperature, minimizing the influence of the original temperature (while also providing a separate mechanism of cooling). This would also contribute to the difference for different temperatures being imperceptible. In any case, the coupled heat–mass transfer problem becomes more complex, as you may need to consider the exposed area, temperature distribution inside the water container, and boundary conditions that mediate the heat and mass transfer. (In other words, the kinetic process of evaporation depends on more parameters than the thermodynamic energy balance.) Do you have this information? You may wish to migrate to the Engineering Stack Exchange site, which might be more useful in terms of, say, providing recommendations from manufacturers, who have studied this problem in detail.

Comment: So, although the effect is miniscule, you are saying that the net effect will be that in theory, the colder water will provide better cooling effect ? My thinking was that since hotter water needs less heat from air to evaporate , hence it would be better, since it can evaporate easier. But you seem to suggest precisely the opposite, that since colder air needs more heat to evaporate , it is better. Also, you are not taking time into account i.e. is their a difference between how fast , say water at 10°C absorbs Q kJ , vs how fast water at 35°C absorbs Q kJ. Because that matters in this case.

Comment: Also, how doe it compare to how fast , water absorbs Q kj, during the latent heat phase

Comment: In fact i was thinking about this , and i dont think it matters how MUCH heat the water can absorb before evaporating. Because of how the cooler operates, what matters is how fast can the water absorb heat. So , the heat of vaporization plot seems irrelevant. I need to know how fast will the water absorb heat at each of the temperatures. Can you find any data, plots etc. regarding that ?

Comment: " _If the water............evaporates quickly_ "
This assumption is the crux of my question. If water evaporates quickly in both cases, then it is a no brainer, obviously, colder water will absorb more heat. And i agree, the other factors and engineering considerations are also an issue. I guess my question, is more about just the physics of cooling. In other words, with air blowing through them, would water at 10 degrees absorb heat faster than water at 30 degrees ? also putting it in those terms , the answer seems a simple yes. Is it indeed yes, for this specific theoretical question?

Comment: Is there something special about the "evaporation point" where it absorbs heat faster than it does while it is at 10 degrees or at 30 degrees ?

Comment: Also, another silly question. The graph you used, is about the enthalpy of vaporisation. Is vaporisation different than "evaporation" in this context. That plot is about (correct me if i am wrong) , the heat it will absorb to gradually raise its temperature to certain temperature (boiling point ? ) and then vaporise. But, in evaporative cooler, water definitely does not absorb heat , till it reaches that high temperature to vaporise . Here, the water is "evaporating" at a low temperature, right ?

Comment: " _This is a good approximation if the water evaporates quickly under forced convection of hot, dry air_ "  IS this a good approximation? Like i said, *whether* cold air evaporates quickly or not is the point of contention of my question. I am okay with the assumption that room temperature water evaporates quickly, because that is what the machine is designed to do. With cold water, i am not so sure

Comment: " _colder water takes more energy to heat up, and colder water evaporates slower_ " I dont think we are concerned about which takes more/less energy to heat up per se, or which evaporates slower/faster per se. What we need is which absorbs heat faster . Colder water could evaporate slower, but it might be absorbing heat faster i.e heat per unit time, right ?


" _The amount reflects evaporation/vaporization at the given temperature, from liquid water to gaseous water. It does not require boiling._ " Okay, but i am not sure if it reflects the per unit time absorption of this heat.

Comment: " _If the water in both temperature cases is fed at a constant rate and evaporates quickly, then the per-mass enthalpy can act as a surrogate for the per-time enthalpy, giving us an effective cooling power rate._ "
I do not think we can validly assume that water in both cases evaporates quickly. That is part of what is under investigation. If we could assume that , then it is an open and shut case, and the question is completely trivial.

Comment: But surely there must have been some kind of research done on per-time enthalpy just like the one you showed about per-mass enthalpy ? I do not have the knowledge for this, but is there some similar kind of concept in thermodynamics? I find it hard to believe  that scientists all these years have not thought of per-time enthalpy ?

Comment: " _Try comparing the rate at which you need to replenish water. If the rate isn't lower for the colder water, then the above assumption is valid and the specific enthalpy translates easily into a cooling power._ "
" This is a very clever suggestion, but the cooler would have to be run for many several hours on end, to get any perceptible measurement of difference in water consumption. I have access to it at most 20-30 minutes per day. There is no way to make any controlled  discernible measurement of  difference in water consumption for the 2 cases.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on whether or not you are calculating cooling per unit time or cooling per unit water.

Per unit water, you get (a little bit) more cooling.  Besides the enthalpy of vaporization, you get a little bit more cooling as the water absorbs heat to come up to room temperature.

Per unit time, the speed of evaporation will be (slightly) less.  As you mention, the warmer water will vaporize more rapidly.

Neither of these effects are large.  The total budget is dominated by the vaporization.  A 15 degree C difference in the water will be hard to notice.

Comment: I was concerned merely with temperature of the output air, and in which case will it be lower But i guess out of those 2 options, I am concerned with cooling per unit time i.e. which will provide me the most comfort from the heat. I dont care if more water is used. Water is cheap

Comment: " _A 15 degree C difference in the water will be hard to notice._ " The kind of colder water i was thinking was refrigerated water. So, the temperature difference will be closer to 35-40 celsius

Comment: 40 degrees between fridge and room?  My 15 does seem to be a bit low (my fridge is 20 degrees cooler than my tap).  But even 40 degrees requires less than a tenth of the heat of vaporization.  Hopefully you have this in a different room than the fridge.

Comment: If your fridge is only 20 degrees cooler than your tap, then i think either your fridge is busted, or you live in a place where the temperatures are not hot enough to need a cooler in the first place .Where i live, daytime temperatures reach 40-45 , hence the need for cooler

Comment: Of course, if you're getting cold water by cooling it in your fridge, then overall you're probably increasing the temperature of your house, since the heat that the fridge takes out of the water is just dumped into the house, with some extra from the energy needed to run the fridge.

Comment: The fridge is not a variable. It stays on , whether or not i use refrigerated water in the cooler or room temperature water in the cooler. Hence, that is not an issue. You can just assume, the refrigerator is in another room or another house

Comment: It gets hot here, but the water from the tap is not hot (around 22C) and the fridge is 2.5C.  Both will eventually rise to room temperature in the cooler (cooling the room in the process), so only the starting temperatures are relevant, not the room temp.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Okay , my assumption is that the normal water refers to room temperature water and colder water refers to refrigerated water. So, in my case room temp would be relevant . I guess i should clarify that in the question

Comment: @BowlOfRed " _Per unit time, the speed of evaporation will be (slightly) less. As you mention, the warmer water will vaporize more rapidly._ " I have a slight issue with this. We do not care about which vaporizes more rapidly, per se. We care about which absorbs heat more rapidly. So, if cold water absorbs heat more rapidly even without evaporating, while hotter water evaporates but absorbs less heat per unit time while doing so, then colder water will produce cooler air.

Comment: The fridge's duty cycle increases if it's loaded by tap temperature water so it does produce more heat when it contains warmer things.

Comment: @silverrahul your fridge doesn't magically output the same amount of heat regardless of what's put into it. If your fridge is cooling more of its contents then it will produce more heat. Also water from the tap is generally colder than the temp of the air since it's generally underground, which fluctuates in temperature less.

Comment: @alessandro I meant that my fridge always has bottles of refrigerated water in it. Does it matter if i use that refrigerated water in the cooler or let it stay inside the fridge , in terms of what the fridge does ?

Comment: @silverrahul if you put the tap temperature bottles in the refrigerator at night, or when you don't care if your house is slightly warmer then it won't matter. As Kat says, the refrigerator only outputs more heat while it's working to cool something.

Comment: @Kat I meant that my fridge always has bottles of refrigerated water in it.  Its not the case that i would go put tap water in fridge just to cool it to use in cooler. My fridge always has refrigerated water in it, whether or not i use it for the cooler.  "_Also water from the tap is generally colder than....... " I am not sure where you read about tap water,. It seems to have started from something in the comments. My question never mentions tap water. I said room temp water.

Comment: @alessandro Yeah, like i said, the heating effect of fridge does not  matter in this case. The only things to compare are the cooling effect of using room temperature water in cooler vs refrigerated water in cooler. Therefore, i said to assume refrigerator is in another house